Как в Python создать каталог и отсутствующие родительские каталоги?
Как создать каталог по заданному пути, а также создать недостающие родительские каталоги по этому пути, как, например, это делает команда в Bash: mkdir -p /path/to/nested/directory?

А что мешает исполнить именно ее через subprocess.call()?

Начиная с python 3.2 можно вот так:
import os
os.makedirs('dir/subdir/subsubdir', exist_ok=True)

Начиная с python 3.4 (в котором теперь есть модуль pathlib):
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('/home/dail/first/second/third')
path.mkdir(parents=True)

Начиная с python 3.5 у mkdir тоже есть флаг exist_ok:
path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

*на основе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004073
