Как получить доступ к значению индекса в цикле for?
Как получить доступ к индексу при переборе последовательности с помощью for цикла?
xs = [8, 23, 45]

for x in xs:
    print("item #{} = {}".format(index, x))

Желаемый результат:
item #1 = 8
item #2 = 23
item #3 = 45

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/how-to-access-the-index-value-in-a-for-loop

Это перевод? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/how-to-access-the-index-value-in-a-for-loop

@Alexey Ten у него и другие такие же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1581978/251478  повтор https://stackoverflow.com/q/273192/8058325

Не, ну enumerate это ж база вообще, неужели поиск ничего не даёт.

@AlexeyTen, да, это перевод

А, то есть этот и предыдущий вопросы — это даже не нежелание пользоваться гyглом, а возможное нарушение лицензии...

@andreymal буду благодарен за информацию о том, какими правилами это запрещено. На мете есть ряд вопросов, где это обсуждается и там нет явного запрета. Про лицензию также явно указывается. Что в этом плохого, уточни пожалуйста  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/70/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-so

@hedgehogues переводы не запрещены, запрещено нарушение лицензии. И запрещено не правилами сайта, а собственно этой самой лицензией и законодательствами стран, в которых эта лицензия действует

Из ответа на мете: "лицензия на контент позволяет свободно переносить информацию между сайтами, коль скоро указан первоисточник". Однако, в текущем случае ссылки на источник не указано почему-то. Почему?

Сделано, поправил

@andreymal да у него, наверное, каждый вопрос не его, а где то взят.

Использование индексов:
Так как к элементам списка можно обращаться по индексу, то пройдёмся по всем индексам и будем в пару брать соответствующий элемент. Не забудем также, что индексы нумеруются от 0 до длины списка - 1, поэтому будем увеличивать значение индекса на 1 при выводе.
array = [8, 23, 45]

n = len(array)
for index in range(n):
    print(f"item #{index+1} = {array[index]}")

Использование функции enumerate:
Будем перебирать элементы, а функция enumerate будет за нас поддерживать ещё и счётчик. Первым аргументом в enumerate передаём сам список, а вторым значение с которого хотим начать отсчёт, то есть 1.
array = [8, 23, 45]

for index, val in enumerate(array, 1):
    print(f"item #{index} = {val}")


а вторым значение не значение, индекс

@MBo значение индекса ¯\(ツ)/¯
